# C# - Dynamic Type or Typecast?

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic

Talking about performance, what is better in C#? Use Dynamic types or Typecast?

Like this (just an example, not the real implementation):

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(new Woman());
list.Add(new Men());
list.Add(new Car());
....... in another code ....
var men = (Men)list[1];
men.SomeMenMethod();
```

Or this

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new Woman());
list.Add(new Men());
list.Add(new Car());
....... in another code ....
var men = list[1];
men.SomeMenMethod();
```

Comment: Profile it to find out. Write some code which calls the method both ways a million times, and then time it to see which one takes longer. I suspect two things though: 1) you can probably rewrite the code so that you know what types of object are in the list, so that you don't need the casts, and 2) that the performance difference will be negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, don't use either. Try to use type-safe solution that doesn't involve casting or `dynamic`.

If that's not possible, casting is better, because it's more clear, more type-safe (compiler can check that `Men` actually does have `SomeMenMethod`), the exception in case of an error is clearer and it won't work by accident (if you think you have `Men`, but you actually have `Woman`, which implements the same method, it works, but it's probably a bug).

You asked about performance. Nobody other than you can really know the performance of your specific case. If you really care about performance, always measure both ways.

But my expectation is that `dynamic` is going to be much slower, because it has to use something like a mini-compiler at runtime. It tries to cache the results after first run, but it still most likely won't be faster than a cast.

Answer (score 1):

The example is contrived as you know list[1] is a `Men`. So in that case either is identical.

Where dynamic becomes useful where  you don't know the precise type, but you do know that at runtime that it will have a `SomeMethod` or property.

Of course if the type assumption is wrong, then the first throws an exception on the

`var men = (Men)list[1];` line while the latter throws the exception on `men.SomeMenMethod();`